# should I lock 'event'?

Tags: c#, events, locking

should I lock event in the following case:

event foo;

thread A:  will call foo += handler;

thread B:   will call foo -=  handler;

should I lock foo?

Comment: Jon's answer is good, but before answering, I would push back to ask why it is you want to do the lock in the first place. *What problem do you believe you have, and why do you believe locking solves it?*  I can think of multiple problems that you might have around multithreaded events; you'd use different locking techniques depending on which problem you were worried about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Locking on `foo` is a bad idea, because the value will change each time. You should lock on a variable which *doesn't* change:

```
private readonly object eventLock = new object();
private EventHandler fooHandler;

public event EventHandler Foo
{
    add
    {
        lock (eventLock)
        {
            fooHandler += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (eventLock)
        {
            fooHandler -= value;
        }
    }
}

private void OnFoo(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler;
    lock (eventLock)
    {
        handler = fooHandler;
    }
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Note that if you use a field-like event, like this:

```
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

then you'll automatically get a "lock(this)" on add/remove, although you'd have to manually add it when fetching the handler before calling it (assuming you want to make sure you read the most recently written value). Personally I'm not a fan of locking on "this", but you may not mind - and it certainly makes for simpler code.

Comment: @Jon, i am calling the event handler using the event directly, like this foo(), not fetching the handler out of the event, should i add lock?

Comment: @Benny: If you're using a field-like event you don't *have* an add/remove to lock on. If you're calling the event handler directly, how are you guarding against it being null? Note that you can't just use `if (foo != null) { foo(...); }` as `foo` could *become* null after the test. Also it wouldn't guarantee that you'd get the latest value - that's why I've got the locking in my `OnFoo` method. (Memory models can do funny things...)

Comment: Note that the codegen for field-like events will be changing in C# 4 to address the "lock this" code smell. Chris Burrows will be writing a blog about that some time in the next few months; watch his blog for details.